# How to hardcode the value in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

How to hardcode the value in JMeter? We need to hardcode field value for each request. Than after the response I need to crosscheck if the response are exactly matching the with the hard coded one. after that only we will be passing the test case. using Beanshell postprocessor

Comment: as off now I am just making request and getting the response and writing it to another CSV. But our ultimate goal is before writing we need to validate each field of that request . with the predefined value (that we need to hardcode).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match the response against "reference" value the best option is using [JMeter Assertions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#assertions), to wit [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion).

If your assertion logic is more complex than equals/contains/matches which can be implemented using the Response Assertion - be aware that [since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Elements and Groovy language for any form of scripting](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so my expectation is that you should go for [JSR223 Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial) instead.